# How to disable client side validation messages of activeform in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii2

We wish to remove the validation messages to appear on client side validation using activeform on Yii 2.0.

Tried:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['clientOptions'=>['hideErrorMessage'=>false]]);
```

Getting:

> Invalid Call – yii\base\InvalidCallException
>
> Setting read-only property: yii\widgets\ActiveForm::clientOptions

On docs, the best I could found was:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#getClientOptions()-detail

I have no clue what "*The Options*" are, so I guessed "*hideErrorMessage*" due to Yii 1 experience.

Can you please advice, how can we programatically disable the error messages generated, without having to, either create a new template for showing the form, nor doing display:none; with css.

The full activeform call for your consideration:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(
        ['id' => $model->formName(),
            'enableClientValidation'=> true,
            'validateOnBlur'=>false,
            'validateOnType'=>true,
            'validationDelay'=> 1500,
            'clientOptions'=>['hideErrorMessage'=>false]
        ]);
```

The clientOptions was a try/guess.

Then, the form fields, an example:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput()->label(false) ?>
```

Comment: enableClientValidation boolean Whether to enable client-side data validation.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$enableClientValidation-detail

Comment: @Akhil Thayyil: It's true by default I guess. Still, I have enableClientValidation there. The only reason it doesn't appear here on SO, is because I wish not to place the all code here.

Comment: please update the question with your activeform code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['fieldConfig' => ['template' => '{label}{input}']]);
```

Comment: Very very nice. :) Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Gamitg: I also faced similar type of problem. Can you please help me. My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420018/disable-yii-validation-error-message-on-focus-key-up-yii2

Comment: it removes the validation message but still shows the red border highlighted. any idea how to disable that too

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam use `'enableClientValidation' => false` on active form property.