# Disable Yii Validation Error Message on focus / key up - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

As default, error message coming on `keyup` and after `pressing` submit button in form (If any error exist for that particular attribute). Which Is Ok. Working perfectly fine.

But, Is it possible to `disable` error message on `key up`? Means, error message, if any, should come only on pressing submit button.

**View**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'id' => 'register-form']); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name',['inputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control fname','placeholder'=>'First Name']])->label(false); ?>
    .
    .
<p><?= Html::submitButton('REGISTER', ['name' => 'register-button']) ?></p>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionRegister() 
{
  $model = new Users(); // User Model
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

    // For Ajax Email Exist Validation
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax ) {
      Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
      return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
        .
        .
    }
}
```

I found [How to disable client side validation messages of active form in Yii 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372259/how-to-disable-client-side-validation-messages-of-activeform-in-yii-2).

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['fieldConfig' => ['template' => '{label}{input}']]);
```

But, In this answer. Error message neither coming on key up nor on pressing submit button. To show error summary, I need to use `<?= $form->errorSummary($model) ?>`. So, Is there any way to disable `key up` error message and show error message as it was showing before only on `pressing` submit button.

Comment: Try to use `'validateOnChange' => false` in active form property.

Comment: Thanks @GAMITG: tlast I Got it. And, posted answer below too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found in **.../widgets/ActiveForm.php**. One option was there `validateOnBlur` which is by default set `true`. So, I changed it to `false` in my form.

> @Gamitg & @Jithin: Thanks For Your Kind Support.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'id' => 'register-form','validateOnBlur' => false]); ?>
```

Now, It's Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add

> 'enableClientValidation'=>false

to your form options:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([ 'id' => 'register-form','enableClientValidation'=>false]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name',['inputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control fname','placeholder'=>'First Name']])->label(false); ?>
    .
    .
<p><?= Html::submitButton('REGISTER', ['name' => 'register-button']) ?></p>
```

Comment: In this way, it will stop all the validation and will allow user to submit the form. I wanted error to show only at the time of submit.

Comment: Hi @NanaPartykar your form submitting using AJAX Form Submission?

Comment: No. @jithin. How I posted my controller code. It's same.